# How to select only those records which are present in current term in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select records if they have balance in current term i.e Term = '202110'

Balance Table -

```
ID Code Term   Balance
1  XYZ  201920 20
1  HPA  202110 890
2  XYZ  202110 20
2  HCB  202110 529
3  XYZ  201920 20
3  STE  202020 765
```

The Desired output should be -

```
ID Code Term   Balance
1  XYZ  201920 20
1  HPA  202110 890
2  XYZ  202110 20
2  HCB  202110 529
```

As ID - 1 and 2 have balance in Term - 202110.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.term = 202110);
```

If you don't want to specify the term, then you can use the maximum value in the table.  This might be simpler with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(term) over () as max_term
      from t
     ) t
where term = max_term;
```

Comment: wish I could. it does not give the correct result. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want the ids returned by this query:

```
select id from balance where term = '202110'
```

Use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from balance
where id in (select id from balance where term = '202110')
```

Comment: Then you did not explain the requirement correctly.

Comment: @RonitSharma check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97c0e10f3421af010cc21ac129242a01

Answer (score 0):

You can use either In or Exists clause

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID 
IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE TERM = 202110 AND BALANCE > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.